# How to get full control over the console?

Tags: c++, console-application

I am currently writing a C++ program which must be able to show a rotating cube in a terminal. (school assignment). So I start off with a 60*60 array (two-dimensional vector, to be exact) of chars, which I am going to write to the screen. But if I just do this with two for-loops and  `std::cout` I get very ugly output: just the screen under the previous one, endlessly.

So I need something better, I need to do something like what Vim does: it seems to take over the console, and when you are done it dissapears, and you terminal is back. How can I do this?

Comment: This is OS-dependent. Note that the term "console" is generally used in this context only in the Windows world, U**x terminology is "terminal" ("console" has a different meaning there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) to do this.